# How to map the result from a query to a custom object in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm searching a way to tell sqlalchemy to map a complex query over some tabes to a custom class `MyResult` instead of the default `RowProxy` class. Here's a simple working example

```
'''
create table foo(id integer, title text);
create table bar(id integer, foo_id integer, name text);
insert into foo values(0, 'null');
insert into foo values(1, 'eins');
insert into bar values(0,0, 'nullnull');
insert into bar values(1,0, 'einsnull');
insert into bar values(2,1, 'zweieins');
'''
```

and the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from itertools import imap

db = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
metadata = MetaData(db)

class MyResult(object):
    def __init__(self, id, title, name):
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.name = name

foo = Table('foo', metadata, autoload=True)
bar = Table('bar', metadata, autoload=True)

result = select([foo.c.id, foo.c.title, bar.c.name], foo.c.id == bar.c.foo_id).execute().fetchall()
```

Now I'm looking for a way to tell sqlalchemy to perform a mapping from the result rows to MyResult.

```
row = result[0]
print type(row)
#<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.RowProxy'>
print row.items()
#[(u'id', 0), (u'title', u'null'), (u'name', u'einsnull')]
```

I know I can do the mapping by hand with something like

```
my_result = imap(lambda x: MyResult(**x), result)
```

but I have the feeling that this is not the way to handle it in sqlalchemy.

Comment: The example is not really complex, is the real world problem complex? Most importantly though: what is "real-life" relationship between these two tables: a) it is in fact a `1-1 relationship` between tables, and two combined rows represent one "Object" instance (a-la inheritance); b) single Foo can be referenced by may Bars (`1-n relationship`). In this case your mapping would not work, as the `id` column (used as PK) might not be unique. x) are these view-only or would you like to be able to add new DB rows by creating and saving new `MyResult` instances?

Comment: Real world example is a join over 4 Tables. 1-n relationship from snow flake schema. I'm aware of the id problem, but can solve it with either a joined unique id or some other way. Saving instances is not required.

Answer (score 10):

As can be seen from your sample, there will be more than 1 Foo returned for `Foo.id = 0`, which will result in the duplicate value for the primary key, which will in turn only result in a subset of your result-set being returned. In this case you probably should extend the `primary_key` also to other `Bar` columns (either include `Bar.id` or use `Bar.name` if it is unique).

Then you can use the [`from_statement`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement) (as documented in [Using Literal SQL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html?highlight=from_statement#using-literal-sql)) to achieve this:

```
sql_qry = select([foo.c.id.label("id"), 
                  foo.c.title.label("title"), 
                  bar.c.name.label("name")], 
                 foo.c.id == bar.c.foo_id)
my_result_qry = session.query(MyResult).from_statement(sql_qry)
for x in my_result_qry.all():
    print x
```

However, the model `MyResult` has to be mapped. You can map it to some dummy (non-existant) table or view. Also the `label`s for columns are important as they must exactly match your column definitions of the class (the constructor will **not** be used anyways).

Answer (score 5):

By calling `select` directly you are leaving out the ORM features.  You need to use [`mapper`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html) on your `MyResult` class.  As you have it, `MyResult` is just an ordinary class.

Something like this:

```
Foo = mapper(MyResult, foo)
Bar = mapper(MyResult, bar)  # NOTE: MyResult itself is unchanged by this

session = Session()
# query against the mapper class
result = session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.title == 'xyz').one()
print result.name
```

Comment: You can also create a "declarative" base class and then make `MyResult` a subclass of it.  Many people prefer the declarative style but it does have trade-offs.  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html