# Parsing result from sqlalchemy stored procedure execution

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a stored procedure in a postgresql database.

I'm trying to use the function within a python flask app with sqlalchemy. That query looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

appts = db.session.execute(func.getopenappointments(current_user.id))

for appt in appts:
    # work with each appt
```

The result from this query is an object of type sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy. Each iteration of that object looks like this:

```
('(2,"2017-09-15 10:00:00",6,cleaning,available,5)',)
```

The problem is I am used to referring to the columns with something like:

```
for appt in appts:
    print(appt.id)
```

But this fails due to id not existing. What I have realized is the output is pretty much a string that I have to parse with python split() just to get the values I need. How I can keep this a stored procedure but be able to refer to the output by columns, or at least as a tuple and not a regular string?

Comment: Why your record is formatted this way?

Comment: I think that is the key problem. The record is not formatted how I would expect it to be with typical sqlalchemy results. But this is the result I get from executing a stored procedure.

Comment: Do you know the data types of each "field" of your result. What type is "cleaning" and "available"? Strings?

Comment: What DB are you using? How is `getopenappointments` defined? Include a proper [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I updated the question with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10182239/2594812).  There is a construct called `from_statement` that can be used to interpret the results of a SQL statement as an SQLAlchemy ORM model.
So I'm assuming that you have an `Appointment` class that is an ORM mapper, either because you used declarative_base or because you used the mapper function directly.
Then you can do something like

```
appts = db.session.query(Appointment).from_statement(func.getopenappointments(current_user.id))
```

That will run your SQL stored procedure and interpret the result if it is a set of `Appointment` objects.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä link fixed, sorry 'bout that