# SQLAlchemy: fill object with stored procedure or more complicated sql statement

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have an sql alchemy class that I use called Feature.

```
class Feature(DBConnect.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'feature'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(500), nullable=False, default='')
```

In other code I can get a feature by doing:

```
feature = db.session.query(Feature).get(10)
```

And I end up with a feature object. Is there away to do a stored procedure or more complicated query like so:

```
select * from feature f
join aligned_data_column a on a.id=f.aligned_Data_column_id and 
a.aligned_data_id=76
where a.aligned_data_id=70 
union
select * from feature f
join aligned_data_column a on a.aligned_data_id=76
where json_contains(json_extract(f.column_mappings, '$.*'),CAST(a.id as JSON))
```

I was hoping to be able to just input that query into a stored procedure or some where in code. I am using MySQL and python 3.x

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920397/use-raw-sql-in-an-orm-query, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230817/parsing-result-from-sqlalchemy-stored-procedure-execution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181427/how-to-map-the-result-from-a-query-to-a-custom-object-in-sqlalchemy/10182239#10182239